# In Unix ksh, can I pass variables from one script to another ksh script as parameters in that script call, without making them global with export?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

Right now I have:

Script A:

```
export var1="path"
export var2="test"
export var3="message"

/path/to/scriptB "$var1" "$var2" "$var3"
```

This works, and I can access the variable values in the Script B, but I dont want other scripts that call Script B to influence those global variable values. Is there a way to pass the value through the script call without exporting the variables to a global scope first?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you exported the variables, the sub-shells could read them, change them locally, but would never change them in `scriptA` (unless scripts are called sourced with `.` prefix)

Anyway, since you're passing the variables as *arguments* of `scriptB`, you don't even have to `export` them.

```
var1="path"
var2="test"
var3="message"

/path/to/scriptB "$var1" "$var2" "$var3"
```

Just reference them as `scriptB` arguments: `$1`,`$2` and `$3`

If you *really* want to access them with their names in `scriptB` just do this in `scriptB`

```
var1="$1"
var2="$2"
var3="$3"
```